Is there a way in Kotlin to provide code which whould always be executed *after* class contruction?
I have a class in Kotlin which I never want to be instantiated via the primary constructor. Both secondary constructors wind up initializing a property based on their parameters, and I want to be sure the property is initialized (which it won't be with the primary constructor).
I'd like to declare my property to be lateinit, and then test to ensure it was initialized before any class methods are executed (e.g. as a final step of construction), to generate some kind of meaningful error. I don't want to have to introduce guards into every class method.
Here's an example:
class ElementsContainer() {
    private lateinit var elements: Elements

    constructor(url: String): this() {
        val doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
        elements = doc.body().select("*")
    }

    constructor(newElements: Elements): this() {
        elements = newElements
    }
 ...
}

Is there a way for my class to validate that elements has been initialized as a final check at the end of construction (via this::elements.isInitialized), and fail construction if not (e.g. throw an exception)?

it is not very good idea to mix downloading from url and element list in one class, declare you class with primary constructor which accept elements and then use another class to download elements and instantiate container

is connecting to the url and reading the body of the doc a function of the ElementsContainer class?  Do you want the same Container object to connect to multiple urls and overwrite its elements?  or Should this behavior be done outside the class and then the elements list passed into your constructor?  In the second scenario you can check before initializing your object if the elements list is empty.  In the first scenario you can construct your object, then perform the tasks, then perform a check for empty elements.

@ilya-bursov I don't know why I didn't think of that lol. Thanks.

You can make the primary constructor private if you don't want it to be used:
class ElementsContainer private constructor() {
    // ...
}

But if you always want elements to be available, you should make it mandatory for the primary constructor:
class ElementsContainer(private val elements: Elements) {
    constructor(url: String) : this(Jsoup.connect(url).get().body().select("*"))
}


Thank you for answering the actual question. Lots of useful comments in other responses which I certainly appreciate, but they do not address how to do this in a situation where it is necessary. I certainly won't be doing this in my current example (I admit it - this was an ugly approach to my particular problem), but it's good to know how it can be done, when appropriate. Kudos.

One of your secondary constructors simply puts the Elements instance in the private property. The other seems more like a "utility function" for creating an Elements instance than a constructor. This could probably be better implemented like so:
class ElementsContainer(private val elements: Elements) {

    // ...

    companion object {

        fun fromUrl(url: String): ElementsContainer {
            val doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
            val elements = doc.body().select("*")
            return ElementsContainer(elements)
        }
    }
}

The elements property can still be var if you need it to be. It may also be better to move fromUrl to a separate object or even to a top-level function.
